# Warning message should contain a LINK to a next page

Tags: python, django, django-templates

If the user has no username I am displaying an warning message on their profile page. In it I want to set a link to a page where the user can set their username. I have done this like this but the a href is displayed as a string. What is the problem?

```
messages.warning(request, 'WARNING! You have not set your custom URL for this profile. You can set this <a href="{% url change_url %}">HERE.</a>')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages are just strings, not template instructions. To get your url you should use [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse    

messages.warning(request, 'WARNING! You have not set your custom URL for this profile. You can set this <a href="%s">HERE.</a>' % reverse('change_url'))
```

To turn off django template escaping use `safe` filter:

```
{{ message | safe }}
```

Comment: still the same result. It renders the a href tag too

Comment: @mangobug How do you output the messages in template? See edits.

Comment: in the base.py file i simply put the messages in a loop and render it <p>{{ message }}</p>